# Let $f(x)=(x+1)/x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x\not= 0$ prove that this function is one-to-one correspondence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions

Let $f: R\setminus\{0\} \rightarrow R\setminus\{1\}$ be a function defined by the formula $f(x)=(x+1)/x$  for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \not= 0$ prove that this function is one-to-one correspondence , I already proved that this function is one-to-one but I can't prove that it is onto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* Solve $(x+1)/x=y$ for $x$ when $y\ne1$.